# React - map array to child component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm coding a site with multiple pages. A page `ComponentA`, have a child component that return sections with titles and paragraphs.

The array in `ComponentA` pass data as props to the child. Inside the child, a map function return the paragraphs correct. What's missing for the titles, how would you do to pass `title1` to `paragraph1`, `title2` to `paragraph2` and so on?

ComponentA:

```
import Child from "../components/child";

const ComponentA = () => {
  <Layout>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    <Child title={info.title} text={info.text} />
  </Layout>
}

const info = {
  title: ["Title1", "Title2"],
  text: ["Paragraph1", "Paragraph2"]
};
```

Child component:

```
const Child = ({ text, title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {text.map(text => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <p>{text}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `info` object is not an *iterable list* - so I would convert them into a list `{title, text}` like so:

```
const data = info.title.map((e,i) => {
  return {title : e, text: info.text[i]}
})
```

Now I would shift the `map()` function to `ComponentA` instead of `Child` as that makes the child component more *meaningful*.

See demo below:

```js
const info = {
  title: ["Title1", "Title2"],
  text: ["Paragraph1", "Paragraph2"]
};

const data = info.title.map((e,i) => {
  return {title : e, text: info.text[i]}
})

const ComponentA = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      { data.map(item => {
          return (
            <Child key={item.title} title={item.title} text={item.text} />
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

const Child = ({ text, title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <ComponentA/>, 
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your children component like this, since `text` is an array so you need to access it values by index.

```
const Child = ({ text, title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {text.map((text,index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h3>{title[index]}</h3>
            <p>{text}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

You can even change you parent component to something like this

```
import Child from "../components/child";

const ComponentA = () => {
  <Layout>
    <h1>Home Page</h1>
    {info.text.map((text,index)=> <Child title={info.title[index]} text={text} />}
  </Layout>
}

const info = {
  title: ["Title1", "Title2"],
  text: ["Paragraph1", "Paragraph2"]
};
```

And then your child should be

```
const Child = ({ text, title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
          <h3>{title}</h3>
          <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over text and usnig index access the title

```js
const ComponentA = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
      <Child title={info.title} text={info.text} />
    </div>
  )
}

const info = {
  title: ["Title1", "Title2"],
  text: ["Paragraph1", "Paragraph2"]
};

const Child = ({ text, title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {text.map((text1, index) => {
        return (
          <div>
            <h3>{title[index]}</h3>
            <p>{text1}</p>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<ComponentA />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"/>
```